# Bootstrapping all inbound requests via API gateway

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

This may seem like an interesting/odd request but I was wondering if there's a way API gateway could be taught to respond to all requests as to act as a bootstrap/route manager for an API layer? Basically all requests ie. /getUser, /getLocation, /getManager could be written as one API Gateway endpoint rule?

Here's the idea...all GET requests no matter the path on the API get routed to a Lambda function which parses the request and envokes the proper delegate function.

Similar rules would be setup for POST, DELETE and PUT. So basically the API gateway would only have 4-5 registered points that all map to the same Lambda function.

I'm conducting some early research into different patterns/approaches to gateway usage and was wondering if it would be possible to factor something such as this. There's advantages and disadvantages to this but I just want to know if it could be scripted this way.

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't this functionality somehow similar to a reverse proxy?

Comment: Currently, API Gateway doesn't support this. Please contact AWS team to submit a feature request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use request path parameters with API Gateway.

You could create several endpoints like these ones:

```
GET /{param1}
GET /{param1}/{param2}
GET /{param1}/{param2}/{param3}
```

These endpoints should match whatever url that has up to 3 path parameters. They can be configured to call the same Lambda.

In the integration request configuration, we could use something like this for the mapping template (we could add data from the body, query string and header too ...):

```
{
  "endpoint": {
    "path": "/$input.params('param1')/$input.params('param2')/$input.params('param3')",
    "method": "$context.httpMethod"
  }
}
```

Then in the lambda event, we would be able to know the HTTP method and the resource path and execute the appropriate portion of code.

An **advantage** would be to **use more often the same lambda and improve its average performance**. Indeed, if you make successive calls to a lambda, [chances are that AWS re-use the same container to execute it](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/container-reuse-in-lambda/) and you don't need time to "warm it up". Using the same lambda more often should reduce the proportion of "warm up" depending on the frequency of executions.

A **disadvantage** is to **loose the "microservice" aspect** of using Lambda because all your application would be embed in only one Lambda. Another disadvantage of course is that you will have to **code routing rules and execute them in the Lambda**.

Comment: Thanks for the insight! For our particular use we can easily mitigate the routing issue and yes it does take away from the microservices concept. For that matter it also makes logging less viable b/c all inbound requests are treated the same by CloudWatch. It's an interesting option though.